# What's the best way to code an app in which objects must interact with each other in complicated ways?

Tags: oop, command, state

I am interested in a general approach, not a particular library or framework.

I am trying to avoid spaghetti-code-ish conditionals when possible. It may be that I'm thinking of these apps in totally the wrong way, but I can't seem to find anything online that's helpful.

The problems arise when there are multiple sorts of states that all affect each other. Here's an example:

Image a Person that has these abilities:

Walk.
Run.
Sit.

I make a command pattern with Walk.execute(), Run.execute() and Sit.execute(). These commands are triggered by user input or whatever. What's great about this, of course, is that if running needs to be debugged or amended, it's easy to know where to look in the code base.

Now I'm asked to add a dog. The dog can...

Walk.
Run.
Sleep.

If the person is walking and the dog is running, the dog (being on a leash) will run slower than he will if he's running on his own. And if the dog is sleeping, the person will sit for longer than he normally does. In other words, the dog and the person are affected by each other.

Then I'm asked to add a refrigerator with food in it. The fridge affects the dog and person, because the amount they eat affects their energy for running, etc.

I am continually asked to tweak this system. "Please make the dog run sleep more, but only if he and the person have been walking and the fridge is almost empty." And then, later: "Please change it so that the amount the person has run has walked has no affect on the dog's sleep."

I want to avoid packing DogSleep with tons of conditionals, and I also want to avoid DogSleepIfDogAndManHaveBeenWalkingAndFridgeIsAlmostEmpty. That's not scalable.

At any time, we might want to rip the fridge out of the system. Or we might want to change it in some fundamental or subtle ways.

A more real-life example is a media player that can be displayed as a compact player, an expanded player (say one that takes up half of your screen) and a full-screen player. So there are those three screen states.

Meanwhile, the player could be displaying an image, video or text.

If it's displaying a video, that video could be playing, paused, completed, etc.

The state of the video affects the way the different screen states render. The type of media also affects the rendering. And the screen state affects things the other objects (e.g. maybe, for whatever reason, you're supposed to be able to pause a video when the player is compact but not when it's expanded or in full screen).

What is the best way to make multiple state systems interact with each other when those interactions are complex and flow in both (or multiple) directions? How can one organize such code so that it's easiest to debug and scale?

Answer (score 0):

The primary way to manage complexity in complex systems is to find analogies and concepts in the real world upon which you can base your design **and** implementation.  So, when you talk about people, dogs and refrigerators interacting in some system you base methods of interaction on the way these entries interact in the real world - which is largely autonomously based on sensed inputs and internal interests/goals/needs.  When you talk about media players and images and text then finding the analogies is more difficult but just as important.

Comment: The problem with real-world analogies is that they can be extremely complex and ugly, e.f. "If I see I dog, I should run, unless that dog is very small or is Fido."

Comment: That logic __must__ be somewhere in some form.  Maybe you code it is a 'fear index'.  if (fear > threshold) then flee.  And a large dog increments your 'fear'.  This is how people make decisions; thus it really is the __only__ basis for coding it.